# How to copy a sheet so that button affects copied sheet, not original sheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, spreadsheet

I created the code below on OrignalSheet0. Using a macro I then create ten copies, OrignalSheet1, OriginalSheet2.... But when pressing the button on OriginalSheet1 (or any of the newly created sheets for that matter), the button affects OriginalSheet0. I've googled and cannot find out how to fix this.

Here is the code:

```
'Change Tab Color
'This is run when a button is pressed
    Sub ChangeTabColorToGreen()
    Me.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

Comment: I can clearly see the problem is in the "Assign Macro to Button" dialog box, but can't figure out how to prevent the problem. Please note, the names of the new sheets change from time to time.

Comment: `activesheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 4`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword

Comment: Perfect: thank you!    SOLVED

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

As suggested in the comments, the issue is that the `Me` does not limit the command's scope to the sheet of interest. You need to set the scope to the current sheet using `ActiveSheet`.

**Answer**

Therefore, the new correct code is:

```
Sub ChangeTabColorToGreen()
    ActiveSheet.Tab.ColorIndex = 4
End Sub
```

**FYI:**

`Me` is used for referring to specific instances of a class and passing information between procedures in different modules. More information can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword